# Show that a language is regular

Tags: formal-languages, automata, regular-language

Show that language $B$ is regular:
$$B = \left\{1^ky\mid y\in \{0,1\}^*\right\} $$
$y$ contains $\ge k$ symbols $1$

So I try in following way - I'll draw DFA:
What about my solution? Is it good?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a fixed $k$, the concept of your solution is good, though there are a few things you can improve/correct:

$1)$ For the first $k$ states (that is state $0$ through state $k-1$), you should also define a $0$ going to some nonaccept state which then loops to itself.

$2)$ A minor correction is needed - you should label the state after the first $k$ state as $1$, not $0$ (because when you get to the green accept state $k$ with the way you currently have it we need to have seen another $(k+1)$ $1$s after the initial $k$ 1s, and we only want to require seeing another $k$ $1$s)

$3)$ Finally, there's no need to have an accept state after the green accept state $k$ - you can just loop back to that accept state because whenever you get to that point in the DFA you want to accept all strings regardless of later input.

Comment: What do you mean when you said: For a fixed $k$ ?  I understand it, but is it good solution  ?

Comment: @user220688 It is just not clear from the question whether we want to look at string of the given form for some particular $k\in\mathbb{Z}^+$ or we whether we want to look at all strings of the form $1^ky$ where $k$ can be anything. However, it is probably for a fixed $k$, because the other possibility is rather trivial.

Comment: Be honestly with you I don't see difference. Help me please

Comment: @user220688 The technical difference is $\{1^ky~|~y\in\{0,1\}\}$ vs. $\{1^ky~|~y\in\{0,1\},k\in\mathbb{Z}^+\}$ (with the same requirement that $y$ has at least $k$ $1$s). The second case is trivial because all you need to check is that a word starts with $1$ and then has at least one more $1$.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, So I upload correct $DFA$.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Automata are not needed to answer your question. Denote by $|u|_1$ the number of occurrences of the letter $1$ in a word $u$. Setting $A = \{0,1\}^*$ and
$$
  L_k = \{u\in A^* \mid |u|_1 \geqslant k \} \qquad B_k = \{1^ku \mid u \in L_k \}
$$
one gets immediately 
$$
L_k = (A^*1)^kA^* \quad \text{and} \quad B_k = 1^kL_k = 1^k(A^*1)^kA^*
$$
and thus $L_k$ and $B_k$ are regular.

It is not really clear whether $k$ is fixed in your question, but even if you take **any** union of languages $B_k$, it will still be regular. Indeed, since $\{1\} \subseteq A^*$, one has for $k > 0$
$$
B_k = 1^k(A^*1)^kA^* \subseteq (1^{k-1}A)A^*(A^*1)^{k-1}A^* \subseteq 1^{k-1}(A^*1)^{k-1}A^* = B_{k-1}
$$
and thus
$$
B_0 \subseteq B_1 \subseteq B_2 \subseteq \dotsm
$$
Setting, for any subset $S$ of $\mathbb{N}$, 
$$
B_S = \bigcup_{n \in S} B_n
$$
one gets $B_S = B_s$ with $s = \min S$ and thus $B_S$ is regular.

Comment: I quoted my question from book. I don't know what does mean that $k$ is not fixed. I assumed that is fixed, but when it is not fixed ?